# How to get latitude and longitude of youtube video from videoid?

Tags: youtube, youtube-api, youtube-data-api

hello friends i am using youtube search api

https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?pageToken=CDIQAA&part=snippet&location=40.748817%2C-73.985428&locationRadius=1km&maxResults=50&type=video

but in response i am not getting location attributes . I have only  channel Id and  video id and i want posted location .

Answer (score 0):

Tested your search query, it returned a 200 OK but with no results and when I changed the query to 10KM radius, I got 23 results. Anyhow, the location details you are searching are a part of `recordingDetails` as shown [here](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos). Scroll down to Resource Representation on that page. This is an optional parameter and does not necessarily have to be included. However, `recordingDetails` are a part of the [Videos List](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/list) and Search endpoint doesn't allow you to query those. So you might have a better chance querying the Videos List endpoint.

Scroll down to the bottom of Videos List link and enter the following value to see what I mean:

- part - snippet,recordingDetails
- chart - mostPopular
- maxResults - 50

This endpoint accepts Video ID as an input and would allow you to search for a video using it's ID.

As you can also see in the [Videos Insert](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert) endpoint, these are optional parameters left for the uploader to define. Hence, if you're not getting any results it probably means they were not defined for that video.